# Micronaut Injected BeanContext cannot retrieve beans

Tags: java, micronaut

In my application that is not a webservice application, so doesn't provide a rest endpoint, I'm using an injected `BeanContext` to create instances of other beans whenever I need them. Those beans are `@Prototype` beans, not `@Singleton` as they should only exists when needed and discarded after use.

The code worked fine with micronaut 3.6.3 but when I upgrade to 4.2.2, the injected BeanContext cannot find any bean. `beanContext.getBean(ProtoTypeBean.class);` will throw a `NoSuchBeanException`

To clarify what I mean, I have a reproducible case in [my github repository](https://github.com/auricgoldfinger/micronaut-daemon).

A simplified version of the code looks like this:

The main application starts the `ApplicationContext` which creates an instance of ScheduleReader and calls `run()`

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (final ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContext.run()) {
        context.getBean(ScheduleReader.class).run();
    }
}
```

In the `ScheduleReader.run()` method, I use the injected `BeanContext` to create an instance of another Bean

```java
@Singleton
@Slf4j
public class ScheduleReader implements Runnable {

   private final BeanContext beanContext;

   @Inject
   ScheduleReader(final BeanContext beanContext) {
      this.beanContext = beanContext;
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      beanContext.getBean(Action.class).run();
   }

}
```

`Action` is a `@Prototype` as well, but at this point, I get the following exception:

```
12:22:29.946 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR com.example.ScheduleReader - Error while starting Action: No bean of type [com.example.Action] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.NoSuchBeanException: No bean of type [com.example.Action] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultBeanContext.java:2773)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultApplicationContext.newNoSuchBeanException(DefaultApplicationContext.java:304)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.resolveBeanRegistration(DefaultBeanContext.java:2735)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:1729)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:856)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext.getBean(DefaultBeanContext.java:848)
    at com.example.ScheduleReader.runPlanner(ScheduleReader.java:41)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

When I use another `ApplicationContext.run()` in `ScheduleReader`, then I can use that application context to retrieve other beans, but I cannot imagine you now have to start ApplicationContexts every time you want to create a new instance of a bean...

The Micronaut guides are focused on launching applications with rest controllers, but as said, this is just a stand-alone application that doesn't expose endpoints. I also didn't find any clue in the migration guides on what was changed or how to solve this problem.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does the head of the Action class look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScheduleReader` uses a `ScheduledExecutorService` to regularly fire a new cycle of functionality. This runs in the background and causes the `run` method to finish. This will activate the autocloseable which will fire the `DefaultBeanContext#stop()` method.

The bean definitions are stored in the `beanDefinitionClasses` cache of the `DefaultBeanContext`. Previous versions of Micronaut didn't clear this cache when calling `DefaultBeanContext#stop()` but current versions do clear it.

So, because the `main` method finishes and the autocloseable is closed, the cache is gone by the time that the `ScheduledExecutorService` fires its first cycle.

One solution is to block the `run()` method so that it never finishes and the autocloseable never stops. Another solution could be to remove the try() around the autocloseable and never call the `.stop()` method, so that the cache is never cleared. But in my opinion, the latter is not a clean solution.

I pushed my solution to [the repository](https://github.com/auricgoldfinger/micronaut-daemon) in separate commits and will keep it up for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you call getBean() instead of createBean(). The get methode works for the ApplicationContext because the application context instantiates all beans initially but the beancontext lazy loads them. If you look at the implementation of getBean() and follow the methode calls you will find in DefaultBeanContext.java the following methode:

```
    @NonNull
    public <T> T getBean(@Nullable BeanResolutionContext resolutionContext,
                         @NonNull Argument<T> beanType,
                         @Nullable Qualifier<T> qualifier) {
        ArgumentUtils.requireNonNull("beanType", beanType);
        return resolveBeanRegistration(resolutionContext, beanType, qualifier, true).bean;
```

the last line throws your exception.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but using the `createBean()` didn't fix the issue. However, your comment triggered me to start debugging the Micronaut code and I found the solution which I described [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77795054/5094336).